# How to use python socket to send data from a driving simulator PC to a laptop?

Tags: python, sockets, struct, udp, port

### Goal

A driving simulator PC generates real-time data (1/60th of a second) that I can get via `socket`. I connected a laptop to this PC via ethernet cable. Now, I want to send the data from PC to the laptop OR get the data directly in laptop via `socket`. Following is the setup:

[image]

### routeTable.txt specifies how to get data from the simulator

Following text file is located at `DrivingSimulator/bin.x64` on PC. I have put the stars `*` to highlight the IP address and ports

```
rem This is  a test for vehicle position
rem name                                        type    size
var
    FrameNum                                    i       1
    VDS_Chassis_CG_Position                     d       3
end
rem Here we format each variable for output, we can change the size of the output here if we want
rem DevID   type    size    is Expr/Name    Name or Expression
device
    1       i       1       n       "FrameNum"
    2       d       3       n       "VDS_Chassis_CG_Position"
end

rem These are the input devices
rem id  CellName                                    offset(byte)    size(Byte)
input
      
    
end

rem ID  **IP address**  **In port** **Out port**    Packed?     List of devices
route
    1   **127.0.0.1**   **9000**    **9001**            1           2
end
```

### UDP.py contains the code to get data in PC in python via `socket`

The following python script when run on PC, prints out the data in python console successfully:

```
import socket
import struct

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 9000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    fields = struct.unpack_from('=ddd', data)
    print(fields[0],fields[1],fields[2])
```

##### Print

[image]

### How do I get the same data on the attached laptop?

#### What I tried:

The laptop is connected to PC via an ethernet cable. I tried running the `UDP.py` script on the laptop, it did not print out anything on the terminal, but also did not throw any error. Then I thought I should use the IP of the laptop. So, I tried that by changing the `UDP_IP` in `UDP.py` and the `IP address` in `routeTable.txt` with the laptop's IP i.e., `192.168.x.yy`. Same behavior: no print out but also no error.

#### Question:

How do I get the data on the laptop?

Comment: Replace sock.bind() with `sock.sendto("hi".encode(), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))` and update UDP_IP with IP addr of the PC. Are you able to ping the PC from the laptop using PC's IP address?

Comment: @CodeMonkey I used `sock.sendto` with PC's IP on the laptop. It runs without throwing the error, but does not print out the `fields`. I am confused where the script must be run, PC or laptop?

Comment: Have you first tried client python code running on the PC that receives data from the simulator?

Comment: @CodeMonkey yes. I think it is the laptop that is the client. The driving simulator software runs on the PC (server)

Comment: Right but can you successfully connect to the driving simulator and get data? If so then connecting from another machine is doable. Is driving simulator source code available or a closed "black-box" application/service?

Comment: @CodeMonkey, thanks for your help. Yes, I can successfully connect between PC and laptop via `socket`. I will update the question with all the relevant code. The source code of the simulator is not relevant though.